# Error in SQL Server query object are closed

Tags: sql-server, vba, project

I want to know why my query has been returning error 3704. on line

```
If Not rsRisks.EOF Then
```

Code:

```
Conn.ConnectionString = sConexaoProjectServer Conn.Open

strSql = "SELECT RiskID, Title " & _
         "FROM [WebCarioca-ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_WssRisk]"

rsListRisksID.Open strSql, Conn

strSql = "SELECT " & _
            "RiskID as Id," & _
            "Title as Titulo," & _
          "FROM    [WebCarioca-ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_WssRisk]"

Dim iLinha As Integer
iLinha = 2

If Not rsRisks.EOF Then
   While Not rsRisks.EOF
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(iLinha, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TrimNull(rsRisks("Id"))
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(iLinha, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TrimNull(rsRisks("Titulo"))
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(iLinha, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TrimNull(rsRisks("Atribuido"))
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(iLinha, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TrimNull(rsRisks("Status"))
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(iLinha, 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TrimNull(rsRisks("Exposicao"))
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(iLinha, 6).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TrimNull(rsRisks("Categoria"))
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(iLinha, 7).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TrimNull(Format(rsRisks("DataVencimento"), "dd/mm/yyyy"))

       iLinha = iLinha + 1
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Rows.Add (-1)

       rsRisks.MoveNext

   Wend
   Else
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(2, 1).Merge MergeTo:=PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(2, 7)
       PPT_Slide.Shapes(2).Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Não existem riscos cadastrados para este projeto."
   End If

   rsListRisksID.Close
   rsRisks.Close
   Conn.Close

   iSlideAcompanhamentoPendencias = iSlideAcompanhamentoPendencias + iDuplicateSlides - 1
   iSlideAcompanhamentoProblemas = iSlideAcompanhamentoProblemas + iDuplicateSlides - 1

   iSlideAcompanhamentoRiscos = 0
```

If anyone can help me, I will appreciate it. Thank you I was using the project professional 2013 and sharepoint 2013 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point in the published code do you open rsRisks.

You open rsListRisksID here:

```
rsListRisksID.Open strSql, Conn
```

But not rsRisks. I suspect you mean:

```
strSql = "SELECT " & _
            "RiskID as Id," & _
            "Title as Titulo," & _
          "FROM    [WebCarioca-ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_WssRisk]"

rsRisks.Open strSql, Conn
```